# ¿Cómo solucionar error preflight CORS? Petición desde aplicación Ionic 2

Tags: java, api, ionic2, cors

He desarrollado una pequeña *API* en *JAVA* con *servlets*, cuando intento consumirlo desde me sale este error:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost/8100' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.

**La petición desde el cliente:**

```
guardarTrabajadorPOST(): Promise < any > {
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Access-Control-Request-Origin', 'http://localhost/8100');
headers.append('Access-Control-Request-Headers', 'Content-Type');
headers.append('Access-Control-Request-Methods', 'POST');
let body = JSON.stringify(this.trabajador);
let options = { headers: headers };
return new Promise(resolve => {
  this.http.post(this.URL, body, options)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
      resolve(data);
    });
});
```

};

Me pasa este error cuando hago peticiones tipo *POST*, con peticiones tipo *GET* he probado y funciona correctamente.

Comment: Bienvenido Mayer!, te sugiero leer [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y realiza el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Con respecto a tu pregunta veo que soporta también el método POST, porque no agregas información sobre como realizas la petición? estas agregando 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' en el header?

Comment: Gracias por la recomendación, lo tendré en cuenta.

Comment: gracias por editar tu pregunta, quedo mucho mejor!, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Como dijo Jorgesys, posiblemente te falta agregar el siguiente header en lado servidor:

PHP: `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`

El ***** le da acceso a cualquier origen.

Mas info:  [the requested server should allow the cross origin sharing of resources (CORS)...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33820142/getting-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check-no-access-control-allow-orig)